# How to query Active Directory through attributeID (urn:iod) by ldapsearch or Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap, openldap, urn

I need to query AD by attributeID like: `urn:oid:2.5.4.42`

Instead of friendlyname: "givenname"

How should I query AD by URN:OID?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is something wrong with the names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just replace the attributeName with its OID in the LDAPFilter like this:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(2.5.4.42=Oliver))
```

This would find all user objects with givenName "Oliver"...